# Denied immigration to the US, can I go back as a tourist?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens

I'm a Canadian citizen.  A few years ago I was offered a job in the USA.  When I got to the border I wasn't allowed to enter - apparently the proper paperwork wasn't in place for me to work in the USA.

Can I go back as a tourist now?  Will that cause any problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you go to the US as a tourist - yes, Will the past cause any problems - likely.

Your early refused entry will be in the system and likely the CBP agent will see it on their screen when you are processed.  You can expect a longer round of questions and probably secondary questioning (ie away from the initial counter).  But assuming you didn't make a scene at your earlier refusal and the reason was as innocent as paperwork not being in place, then they may well let you visit.  But really it is up to the agent processing you, no guarantees.

Comment: (+1) I am not sure but I think that applying for a visa could be a way to avoid problems, do you know about this?

Comment: I'm not even sure if Canadians can _get_ tourist visas. In any case the visa does not guarantee you will be admitted, as it does in some countries.